# heroku scale web=1 fails with "record not found" - procfile problem?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a procfile:
`web: node index.js`

When I run "heroku scale web=1" I get the error `Scaling web processes... Record not found`.  I can't find any explanation of this error or what might cause it, but as far as I can tell it means heroku scale couldn't find a "web" entry in the procfile it attempts to use.

I've deployed my app, I can run `heroku run node index.js` on the server and see no errors.  I can run `foreman start` locally and it starts up a fully functioning instance of my app.

As far as I can tell it seems that the `heroku scale` command just isn't seeing the contents of my procfile (and I know the deployed version is identical to my local version - I checked with `heroku run nano index.js`).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I just want to resolve how to get `heroku scale web=1` working for me.

Answer (score 24):

And the answer is... heroku uses a case sensitive filesystem and expects "Procfile", not "procfile".  Locally I have a case insensitive filesystem and so I can run `foreman start` just fine.

Changing the file to Procfile and doing another push resolved the problem and I was able to run `heroku scale web=1` without further issue.

Comment: OMG thank you. That is a huge gotcha that burnt me for several evenings trying to use Heroku from Mac OS.

Answer (score 4):

If you have not pushed your Procfile to Heroku, it cannot find it to use the scale command.

Answer (score 2):

Check if there is a space between web and your node command in the Procfile. I don't know it is weird.

I got the same issue, I added a space and re-committed. It worked.
        web: node test.js

Comment: I don't know how this isn't a bigger issue or why this is the only comment I could find regarding a space after the colon in a Heroku Profile. `foreman check` says it's fine without a space in there but Heroku won't have it, throwing a `H14` error with the message, `No web processes running` when I didn't have a space. Maybe it's just me, but it's odd that this isn't a bigger issue since `foreman check` and Heroku disagree on Procfile format.

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced the issued caused by a lowercase 'procfile', however simply renaming the file did not get recognized by git. The solution is explained here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7641259/1203226

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for this link, this is the only thing that got it to work for me!

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for local-specific things that might break down at Heroku's servers.

One example was already given: **Procfile** is case-sensitive.

Another one that I have experienced is the presence of **symbolic links** to files outside of the repo. After fixing that the "Record not found" problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to start your app with the foreman gem:

```
 $ gem install foreman
 $ foreman start
```

Then you can scale your node app:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Comment: This answer is unhelpful - I note in my question I can run foreman start successfully and that my problem is in running the second command.

Comment: Besides foreman runs locally, while heroku runs, errm, somewhere else :) foreman is a good check to see (locally) that the app runs and the Procfile is good *before* pushing to heroku.