# Django on Heroku. No web processes running

Tags: django, heroku, web-deployment, production

I have a Django app which works when I run it locally `heroku local`. When I push my code to heroku `git push heroku main` it pushes without any problem, but when I opening my site it showes an 503 error in console

> 1 GET https://XXX.herokuapp.com/ 503 (Service Unavailable)

inside my logs I get this

> at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=omylibrary.herokuapp.com request_id=lotofnumbers fwd="somenumbers" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552846/no-web-processes-running-django-in-heroku) question I assume that the problem is in ProcFile if more precisely in web. My Procfile looks like this

> web: gunicorn --chdir ./Lib library.wsgi --log-file -

I also tried this

> heroku ps:scale web=1

from previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552846/no-web-processes-running-django-in-heroku). What Is wrong here ?

also `heroku ps` returns `No dynos on mysite`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I named `ProcFile` instead of `Procfile` I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7641259/6687545) I have checked logs of heroku while pushing my app by terminal and I got

> remote: Procfile declares types -> (none)

so if you don't have web process running probably it's because of procfile or the code inside it