# ProcFile declares types -> (none) ProcFile

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I want to host Django server over heroku and my *procfile* looks like this

```
web: gunicorn DjangoHerokuApp.Portfoliowebapp.wsgi
```

and this my file structure both procfile and requirements.txt are in root folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGcTf.png)

and it is giving me this error continously

```
Procfile declares types -> (none)
```

and this my requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.4.1
Django==4.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
tzdata==2021.5
```

Please Help ! I am stuck at this for 2 days

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the reason for "Procfile declares types -> (none)" in Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346221/what-is-the-reason-for-procfile-declares-types-none-in-heroku) It's `Procfile` not `ProcFile`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using
web: gunicorn Portfoliowebapp.wsgi